# Python regex me muestra el resultado totalmente a la inversa

Tags: python-3.x, regex

En esta expresión regular que tengo formulada, los resultados que hacen match son justo los contrarios a lo que yo necesito sacar

```
^(?!.*\b(?:BEAR|DOWN|UP|BULL)\b).*/USDT$
```

Pasando por ejemplo estos valores (uno por uno como texto, no como lista)

```
['BTC/USDT','BTCDOWN/USDT','ETH/BTC','BTCBULL/USDT','ADA/USDT']
```

El código me queda así:

```
import re

pairs = ['BTC/USDT','BTCDOWN/USDT','ETH/BTC','BTCBULL/USDT','ADA/USDT']
regex = "^(?!.*\b(?:BEAR|DOWN|UP|BULL)\b).*/USDT$"

for p in pairs:
  if re.match(regex, p):
    print (p)
```

Lo que intento es quedarme sólo con BTC/USDT y ADA/USDT sin embargo con el actual regex, siguen apareciéndome los registros con "DOWN" y "BULL" por ejemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en tu código. Uno es de sintaxis, el otro ya es de lógica.

El error de sintaxis es que la secuencia `\b` dentro de una cadena se interpreta como el carácter ASCII "Bell" (campana o pitido), y no como dos caracteres separados `\` y `b` que es lo que necesitas para escribir una expresión regular. Esto se arregla o bien "escapando" la barra por el método de poner otra delante y escribiendo  `\\b`, o bien poniendo una `r` delante de la cadena. Este segundo método es más limpio y recomendado en Python. Si una cadena tiene una `r` delante (antes de abrir las comillas), entonces la aparición de la barra inversa dentro  `\` no se intenta interpretar como un carácter especial, sino que se trata como un carácter más, que es lo que necesitas para escribir expresiones regulares.

El error de lógica es que la primera `\b` sobra, pues esa secuencia dentro de una regexp significa "principio de palabra". Al escribir `\b(?:BEAR|DOWN|UP|BULL)` estás indicando que una de las palabras "BEAR", "DOWN", etc encajen *solo si son inicio de palabra*, pero en tu caso de hecho no lo son, son finales de palabra.

Arreglando ambos problemas tu código queda así:

```
import re

pairs = ['BTC/USDT','BTCDOWN/USDT','ETH/BTC','BTCBULL/USDT','ADA/USDT']
regex = r"^(?!.*(?:BEAR|DOWN|UP|BULL)\b).*/USDT$"


for p in pairs:
  if re.match(regex, p):
    print (p)
```

y esto ya imprime lo que esperabas:

```
BTC/USDT
ADA/USDT
```

Comment: Gracias mil abulafia, estoy empezando con las regex y me vuelvo loquísima todavía. tu explicación es estupenda (ya quisiera leer explicaciones así de simples y claras)

Answer (score -1):

Siendo positivo, quieres filtrar los elementos con BTC y ADA, seguidos de USDT. Eso lo puedes lograr con un simple patrón: `(BTC|ADA)/USDT`.

Dada las condiciones del problema, es todo lo que se necesita:

```
import re

pairs = ['BTC/USDT','BTCDOWN/USDT','ETH/BTC','BTCBULL/USDT','ADA/USDT']
regex = "(BTC|ADA)/USDT"

for p in pairs:
  if re.match(regex, p):
    print (p)
```

produce:

```
BTC/USDT
ADA/USDT

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Sí pero no. Yo he puesto de ejemplo una lista de 5. La lista original tiene más de 2000 y además es variable, puede cambiar en cualquier momento por lo que no puedo filtrar "a pelo" ;)

Comment: @VeraCanet. Resolvi el problema que planteaste; si tu problema era otro, mala suerte.

Comment: la verdad es que sí, resolviste el problema, pero en realidad no. Es como que yo pidiera ayuda para pilotar un avión, y tu respuesta fuera "sube al avión y pilota hasta donde quieras". Claro, es una solución pero no es la respuesta que cualquiera sabe que se esperaba. De todos modos, tu aportación seguro que le puede servir a alguien que busque algo más simple de lo que yo necesitaba

Comment: @VeraCanet. Tu pregunta está mal planteada entonces. Las especificaciones son incompletas y el caso de prueba que proporcionas corresponde debilmente con el problema real que quieres solucionar.